# What is the default value of concurrent users can login to ADFS saml authentication?

Tags: adfs

I want to know the default value of concurrent users limit for ADFS saml authentication and also wants to know if ADFS server can show proper message once its limit has been reached. Currently it just shows weired message that "you have successfully signed out"

I want to know how to change the limit and set the proper message for it.

[image]

Comment: Why do you think it is a problem with concurrent users? AD FS itself does not have any concurrency restrictions by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That message is because you have signed out.

ADFS would have some kind of theoretical max. - probably in the tens of thousands because you can scale up and add more ADFS instances to an ADFS farm.

Also it is only involved in authentication. Once you've authenticated ADFS is out of the picture.

But there is no "limit reached" message.

As you get to the limit, it will just run slower.

Comment: Yes, you are right. there is no limit for ADFS users.